# Using xterm on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have installed xterm on WSL2.

Whenever I execute xterm, I get:

```
xterm: cannot load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"
```

I installed several fonts with:

```
 sudo apt-get install xfonts-...
```

But the problem persists. How can I solve this?

Additionally, for some reason sometimes it keeps on printing the letter "w"...

Best regards

Comment: Recommend posting the "w" problem as a separate question.  I've had both of these issues as well and just haven't take the time to resolve, since I typically just use `xterm` as a "simple case" app to make sure WSLg (or other GUI methods) are working.  In my case, by the way, mine prints `d` repeatedly on startup (sometimes, but not always).

Answer (score 1):

To set the font when starting `xterm`, first get a list of your installed fonts with:

```
fc-list
```

You don't mention which distribution you are running, so I'm not sure what fonts you will have.  On Ubuntu on WSL, it looks like "DejaVuSansMono" is installed by default, and it's a nice fixed-width terminal-type font.

You can try it out by launching xterm and specifying the font face (and likely size) with:

```
xterm -fs 14 -fa DejaVuSansMono
```

If that font works for you, you can make it permanent by creating a `~/.Xresources` with:

```
xterm*faceName: DejaVuSansMono
xterm*faceSize: 14
```

And then merge it into your X resources database with:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Also note that the "repeating characters" problem appears to be fixed in the latest Preview WSLg.

Answer (score 0):

To load the default fonts required by xterm try installing the package -
xfonts-base

This fixed the problem for me on Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL-2 of xterm not being able to scale by the CTRL - right-click menu