# Sticky Alt after using Alt+Tab swich applications in WSLg

Tags: windows-11, wsl2

I have a new computer with Win11, and I installed WsLg, and find <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is sticky whenever using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> swiching applications if one of the applications is from the WSLg.

The sticky <kbd>ALT</kbd> can only be deactivated by press <kbd>ALT</kbd> again.

Reboot doesn't fix the problem.

This is a very annoying, and the online posts doesn't solve my problem. Thank you for commenting and helping!

All my system seems to have the newest version:

```
Device name 1-039-11
Processor AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor 3.70 GHz
Installed RAM 32.0 GB
Device ID D3418E8A-2C8C-4EC2-A836-7ABF7E5D9D51
Product ID 00330-71450-76029-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch No pen or touch input is available for this display

Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on ‎1/‎11/‎2022
OS build 22000.708
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.708.0

Linux 1-039-11 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               chen@1-039-11 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 20 hours, 28 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 1922 (dpkg) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.1.16 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adwaita [GTK3] 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: terminator 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X (24) @ 3.700GHz 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   GPU: 3448:00:00.0 Microsoft Corporation Device 008e 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Memory: 529MiB / 15952MiB 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+                             
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/                              
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like it could be the same root issue that I was seeing with a sticking (and repeating) <kbd>D</kbd> key in WSLg and the OP of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1708952/1210833) was seeing with repeated <kbd>W</kbd>'s.

I believe what is happening is that, in some cases at least (probably when combined with a modifier key), WSLg gets "stuck" on one of the most recent keys used before exiting the window.

So in my case, if I exited `xterm` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit the shell, then when I opened another window, <kbd>D</kbd> would repeat endlessly.

Sometimes, when I opened a new Xterm window, it would immediately exit.  In this case, I believe it was repeating the full <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> from the previous window.

Attempting to reproduce your particular problem, if I open two Xterm windows in WSLg, and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between them, I get a repeating `ääää`'s until I press another key.

I can tell you that the "repeating key" problem, at least, seems to be fixed in the latest Preview WSL release.  This release is available for installation on Windows 11 from the Microsoft Store by searching for *"Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview"*.  I no longer see the repeating characters on this release.  (Side-note:  I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> scenario on another computer where I have the released WSL/WSLg).

However, there still seems to be some "weirdness" in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on the latest Preview.  The first <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> seems to go to a hidden window of some sort when tabbing away from a WSLg window.  I have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> a second time to get to the next "real" window.  This is, of course, preferably to the repeating keys issue.

Not that there aren't bugs in the Preview version, but there are a lot of fixes as well.

Comment: Amazing, install "Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview" solves the sticky key problem! The Lord bless you!